# Django How to filter all objects foreign key field

Tags: python, django

table : event_rewards

table : rewards

serializer : EventRewardSerializer

serializer : RewardSerializer

models.py

```
class Reward(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'reward'

 class EventRewards(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, models.DO_NOTHING)
    rewards = models.OneToOneField('Reward', related_name='event_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'event_rewards'
```

serializers.py

```
class EventRewardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EventRewards
        fields = ['event', 'rewards']


class RewardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event_id = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='event_id'
     )

    class Meta:
        model = Reward
        fields = ['id', 'category', 'count', 'image', 'name', 'price', 'event_id']
```

views.py

```
class JoinRewardView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk_event, pk_post, pk_user, formant=None):
        reward_list = Reward.objects.all().filter(event_id=pk_event)
        print(reward_list)
        reward_list_serializer = RewardSerializer(data=reward_list, many=True)
        reward_list_serializer.is_valid()
        print(reward_list_serializer.data)
        return Response(reward_list_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

postman -> all().filter(event_id=1)

[
{
"id": 1,
"category": 1,
"count": 100,
"image": "img3",
"name": "coke",
"price": 1000,
"event_id": 1
}
]

postman -> all()

[
{
"id": 1,
"category": 1,
"count": 100,
"image": "img3",
"name": "coke",
"price": 1000,
"event_id": 1
},
{
"id": 2,
"category": 1,
"count": 10,
"image": "img4",
"name": "coffee",
"price": 2500,
"event_id": 1
}
]

all() -> 2 data -> ok!

all().filter(category=1) -> 2 data -> ok!

all().filter(event_id=1) -> 1 data -> why???

Answer (score 1):

Change ModelSerializer And use Table__Column

serializer.py

```
class EventRewardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EventRewards
        fields = ['event', 'rewards']


class RewardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event_reward = EventRewardSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Reward
        fields = ['id', 'category', 'count', 'image', 'name', 'price', 'event_reward']
```

views.py

```
 def get(self, request, pk_event, pk_post, pk_user, formant=None):
        reward_list = Reward.objects.all().filter(event_reward__event=1)
        print(reward_list)
        reward_list_serializer = RewardSerializer(data=reward_list, many=True)
        reward_list_serializer.is_valid()
        return Response(reward_list_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```